# Rss feed with PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, rss

Hi can Anyone tell me how to process this rss feed in php

http://www.ft.com/rss/companies/travel-leisure

when i am executing the below lines

> $rss = new DOMDocument(); 
>   $rss->load('http://www.ft.com/rss/companies/travel-leisure');

it is giving an error

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: DOMDocument::load(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 8 and head in http://www.ft.com/rss/companies/travel-leisure, line: 11

Thanks

Comment: That error message doesn't appear to match that document. It looks more like you are trying to parse some HTML as RSS … and yet I can reproduce it.

Comment: You need to set a UserAgent string for PHP. The request requires one otherwise it gives 403 error page which is what you are hitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you request `http://www.ft.com/rss/companies/travel-leisure` without a `User-Agent` HTTP request header, you can get an error message back (under a `200 OK` status).

This is a bug in FT's website.

As a work around, I suggest using [cURL](http://php.net/curl) to fetch the data, and then feed a string into `DOMDocument`.

Comment: Can OP just do `ini_set('user_agent', 'some browser UA');` right before the request as well?

Comment: Wow, I wanted to comment that as first on OP's question "Looks like it is an error in the XML (but that could not be on FT)!" Haha, true dat,  high quality global journalism does not make high quality web conform websites I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a dedicated library like [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/) to process your RSS feed ?

```
$feed = new SimplePie('http://www.ft.com/rss/companies/travel-leisure');
$feed->init();
$feed->handle_content_type();

foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item) {
    $permalink = $item->get_permalink();
    $title = $item->get_title();

    // Do what you want...
}
```

I have not tested this code, it's just to show you an example of use. Here the [documentation](http://simplepie.org/wiki/) and an [example](http://simplepie.org/wiki/setup/sample_page) for more explanations.